# +imageResource from R.drawable causes IllegalArgumentException in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I was testing out Jetpack Compose with a new empty JC activity called HomeActivity. I am trying to load a drawable resource into my code. This is my function:

```
@Composable
fun home() {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = typography
    ) {
        val menuIcon = +imageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_menu_24)
        val bottomActions = listOf<Image>()
        var (drawerState, onDrawerStateChangeListener) = +state { DrawerState.Closed }

        BottomDrawerLayout(drawerState = drawerState, onStateChange = onDrawerStateChangeListener, drawerContent = {
            Text(text = "Drawer")
        }) {
            Column(
                crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand
            ) {
                BottomAppBar(
                    navigationIcon = {
                        drawerState = DrawerState.Opened
                        AppBarIcon(icon = menuIcon, onClick = {})
                    },
                    actionData = bottomActions,
                    action = {
                        AppBarIcon(icon = it, onClick = {})
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the JC website, `+imageResource(R.drawable.xyz)` should load the resource as andX.ui `Image` object
`imageResource` function returns `Effect<Image>`, it doesn't crash the app but I don't know how to resolve it to Image object needed for `AppBarIcon`

Some of the Logcat outputs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.craftmyspace/com.craftmyspace.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter bitmap
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        ...os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)


     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter bitmap
        at androidx.ui.graphics.AndroidImage.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
        at androidx.ui.graphics.AndroidImageKt.imageFromResource(AndroidImage.kt:29)
        at androidx.ui.res.ImageResourcesKt$imageResource$1$1.invoke(ImageResources.kt:45)
        at androidx.ui.res.ImageResourcesKt$imageResource$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
        at androidx.compose.ComposerKt.remember(Composer.kt:1867)
        at androidx.compose.EffectsKt$memo$2.invoke(Effects.kt:287)
        at androidx.compose.EffectsKt$memo$2.invoke(Unknown Source:2)
        at androidx.compose.Effect.resolve(Effects.kt:106)
        at androidx.compose.Effect.resolve$default(Effects.kt:843)
        at androidx.compose.Effect.unaryPlus(Effects.kt:115)
        at androidx.ui.res.ImageResourcesKt$imageResource$1.invoke(ImageResources.kt:45)
        at androidx.ui.res.ImageResourcesKt$imageResource$1.invoke(Unknown Source:2)
        at androidx.compose.Effect.resolve(Effects.kt:106)
        at androidx.compose.Effect.resolve$default(Effects.kt:843)
        at androidx.compose.EffectsKt.unaryPlus(Effects.kt:841)
        at com.craftmyspace.activities.HomeActivityKt$home$1$1$1.invoke(HomeActivity.kt:66)
```

HomeActivity.kt:66 is this
`val menuIcon = +imageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_menu_24)`

Comment: Try val menuIcon = imageFromResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_baseline_menu_24)

Comment: resources is not defined. I tried:
val menuIcon = imageFromResource(Resources.getSystem(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_menu_24)
But I get the same error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE: Compose_version = '1.0.0-beta01'**

```
val painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.img)
Image(
       painter = painter,
       contentDescription = "Profile pic",
       modifier = imageModifier,
       contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
  )
```

**UPDATE: 02/09/2020**

In compose version `1.0.0-alpha01` you can use `vectorResource(id = R.drawable.my_vector_resource_id)` to load vector resources.

Ex: `Image(asset = vectorResource(id = R.drawable.my_vector_resource_id))` or `Icon(asset = vectorResource(id = R.drawable.my_vector_resource_id))`

**Old Answer**

I have faced the same issue and observed that `imageFromResource()` and  `imageResource()` can't load vector resources.
You need to create a `effectOf<VectorAsset>` by providing the resource id and use `DrawVector()` to draw vector assets.
You can use below `@Composable` function to draw vector resources.

```
@Composable
fun VectorImage(@DrawableRes id: Int, tint: Color = Color.Transparent) {
    val vector = +vectorResource(id)
    WithDensity {
        Container(
            width = vector.defaultWidth.toDp(),
            height = vector.defaultHeight.toDp()
        ) {
            DrawVector(vectorImage = vector, tintColor = tint)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to return this vector as Image to bottom app bar

Answer (score 4):

Can be made easier

```
   Image(
    vectorResource(R.drawable.folk),
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i solve removing `ic_chat_bubble.xml(anydpi)` from `drawable` **ic_chat_bubble**  resource now it's work fine.

[image]